# Python, mixing PyQt5 and abc.ABCMeta

Tags: python, pyqt, python-2.x, metaclass, cls

I am trying to create an AbstractClass using both abc.ABCMeta and QObject as parents and cannot seems to make it work.

Here is the Base class init. I have Pyqt5 and python 2.7

```
pyqtWrapperType = type(QObject)

class ParamsHandler(abc.ABCMeta, pyqtWrapperType):
    def __init__(self, device_model, read_only=False):
        super(ParamsHandler, self).__init__()
        self.cmd_to_get_data = None
        self.device_model = device_model

class ConfigParamsHandler(ParamsHandler):
    def __init__(self, device_model):
        super(ConfigParamsHandler, self).__init__(device_model)
        self.cmd_to_get_data = Commands.CONFIG_PARAMS
```

I get a TypeError('**new**() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)',) I also have Pycharm suggesting that I use cls instead of self

If I supply 4 arguments, it asks for a string as the first argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using this approach instead:

```
class ParamsHandler_Meta(type(QObject), type(abc.ABCMeta)):
    pass
class ParamsHandlerClass(QObject):
    pass
class ParamsHandler(ParamsHandlerClass):
    __metaclass__ = ParamsHandler_Meta
    def __init__(self, device_model, cmd_to_get_data, read_only=False):
        super(ParamsHandler, self).__init__()
        self.cmd_to_get_data = cmd_to_get_data
```

Answer (score 2):

`abc.ABCMeta` is supposed to be used as a metaclass. So instead of extending it, try:

```
class ParamsHandler(pyqtWrapperType):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
```

Comment: Of course! I changed that, but I still get a TypeError('type() takes 1 or 3 arguments',) . I instantiante the class `ConfigParamsHandler(device_model)`

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: @Fred. The type of QObject is certainly not `type`: it's actually `sip.wrappertype`. Your current code will raise a TypeError (due to a metaclass conflict).